# Can anyone in India get a credit card?

Tags: credit-card, india

Can any citizen of India can get a credit card? Are there any limitations of the credit limit or anything like that or any salary requirements before one can get a credit card?

Comment: There might be two different questions here.1. Under Indian law, who is permitted to have a credit card? which is not within the purview of money.SE and 2. What are the requirements imposed by credit card issuers on applicants for credit cards, and how much credit can be obtained? and this is presumably not too different from most places in the world. You need to show that you have _income_ (not necessarily a salary) or that you have sufficient liquid assets in order to get a credit card, and how much credit you can get depends on the issuer and the money amounts indicated above.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Who issues credit cards? The bank?

Comment: Yes, a bank issues credit cards, which are usually linked to networks such as Mastercard or Visa that provide the bank with various services that the bank needs to administer the card successfully. The bank extends you the credit, and you pay the bank, not Mastercard or Visa. Each bank sets its own levels re how much credit it will extend to you based on your own financial circumstances, and so it is entirely possible that one bank will decline to issue you a credit card while another bank will be happy to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone can apply for a credit card, however not everyone is granted a credit card.

For the Bank to issue you a credit card, they need an assurance that you will be able to repay. Each bank has different norms apart from credit score, they also see your source of income [generally its easy if you are salaried / difficult if you are not]. Some bank also grant credit card if you hold a good amount as Fixed Deposits or PPF.

So in short there are multiple eligibility criteria's, for example:
- Salary is above X amount to get a credit limit of Y. Additionally there may be a number of years of service.
- Certain amount of Fixed Deposits or PPF's or other investments.
- Tax Returns show a good amount of income and tax paid.

The easiest way to get a basic card is to apply to the Bank where you have a savings account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

Good internet is all you need for a credit card application online with instant approval.‭ ‬Nowadays,‭ banks are providing quick service and approving credit cards within a day or two considering you match their eligibility criteria and have the required documents in place. Credit card eligibility in India varies based on the internal credit policies of the bank and the purpose for which the card is availed.‭

Here are the steps that you require to apply for a credit card online:

- Visit your bank's website and click on the credit card‭ '‬apply online‭' ‬option.
- Fill out the application form,‭ ‬which contains your personal details such as name,‭ ‬date of birth,‭ ‬address,‭ ‬contact number,‭ ‬pan card number,‭ ‬etc.
- Post that,‭ ‬you will get a call from a credit card representative of the bank,‭ ‬who will guide you through the entire application process.
- Once approved,‭ ‬a representative from the bank will come to your house and collect the required documents.

Apart from applying for a credit card online,‭ ‬you also have the option to choose your card offline.‭ ‬You can visit the bank directly to apply for a credit card.‭ Also,‭ ‬you will be required to provide important‭ documents such as identity proof,‭address proof, payslips, bank statements, etc to the bank.‭ ‬Once the documentation is done,‭ ‬it will take not more than‭ ‬7-10‭ ‬days to get the card delivered to the mentioned address.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements in India are pretty relaxed. At the same time, be aware that you won't get a high credit limit esp. if you are just starting on this route. They have a CIBIL score that many banks used.

When I started my career, I got multiple offers and took a couple but both were below my monthly salary. I am not an Indian citizen but on my last trip there, I went to a bank to close my account (I worked there a decade ago) and they offered me a credit card. Even the person on the counter was surprised that the bank was offering my a card even though it knew that I am not Indian. So apparently, being an Indian citizen is not a hard requirement.

Answer (score 0):

To apply for a credit card in India, there are several options out there such as all state-owned banks and private banks are offering credit cards.

If you have to choose between private/public sector banks, I would look at private banks such as HDFC Bank, ICICI, Axis among others as public sector banks go through a tedious process when applying for a credit card.

Credit Card Eligibility: The process of eligibility criteria for credit card differs from bank to bank, based on the card you apply will have its parameters. In case you don't meet these requirements then your application will get rejected.

Given the demand for credit cards, banks and financial institutions have made the application processes available on their web portals. Once you have decided on the credit card you want, visit the website of the bank and apply for a credit card. Fill out your basic details in the application. Once you have applied, a credit card representative will get in touch with you. You don’t need to visit the bank to submit documents. They will be collected from you at your doorstep.

After completing the formalities, your request for a credit card will be verified by the bank.

Answer (score -2):

To ensure that your credit card application is approved, you must meet certain eligibility requirements. Each bank or card may have different parameters.

**Credit card eligibility requirements to get a credit card in India:**

1. Age ~ You must be at least 18 years old. However, some banks have a minimum requirement of 21 years. The maximum age requirement also differs, and it generally goes up to 60 years.
2. Annual salary ~ Your annual income determines if you’re eligible for a particular card. The minimum salary required to apply for a credit card in India is around Rs.3 lakh p.a. Although, it’s best to check this criterion with your bank as this requirement differs depending on the card issuer you choose.
3. Nationality or residential status: Citizens, residents, and non-residents can apply. However, there are a few cards that are only available for Indian citizens.

It is vital that you go through the eligibility criteria before applying for a card. Make sure to tick off each criterion in the checklist to improve your chances of getting approved.